# $V=M_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ with the standard inner product. $T_P:V\to V$ is $T_p(A)=P^{-1}AP$ find $T^{*}_{P}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=M_{n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ with the standard inner product
>   and $P\in V$ an invertible matrix.
>
> We define a new operator: $T_P:V\to V$  by  $T_p(A)=P^{-1}AP$.  Find
>   $T^{*}_{P}$

My way:

Let $E=\left\{ e_{1},e_{2},\dots,e_{n^2}\right\}$ be the standard basis of V. As we know it's an Orthonormal basis.
Hence $\left[T_{P}\right]_{E}^{*}=\left[T_{P}^{*}\right]_{E}$ so I'd like to find $\left[T_{P}\right]_{E}$.

$$\begin{pmatrix}\\
\mid &  &  &  & \mid\\
\left[T\left(e_{1}\right)\right]_{E} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \left[T\left(e_{n^2}\right)\right]_{E}\\
\mid &  &  &  & \mid\\
\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

By I'm stuck here since I couldn't find what is $\left[T\left(e_{i}\right)\right]_E$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make use of the following facts below: $\text{tr}(A^*) = \overline{\text{tr}(A)}$ (complex conjugation) and that $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$.
We have that
\begin{align}
\langle T_P(A), B\rangle &= \langle P^{-1}AP, B\rangle \\
&= \text{tr}\left( B^* \cdot (P^{-1}AP) \right) \\
&= \text{tr}\left( (P^{-1}AP)^* \cdot B \right)^* \\
&= \overline{\text{tr}\left( (P^{-1}AP)^* \cdot B \right)} \\
&= \overline{\text{tr}\left(  P^* \cdot \left( A^* (P^{-1})^* B \right) \right)}
\end{align}
Now we swap the order of the matrices $P^*$ and $A^* (P^{-1})^*B\,$ in the trace to get
\begin{align}
\langle T_P(A), B\rangle &= \overline{\text{tr}\left( A^* \cdot \left( (P^{-1})^* B P^*\right)\right) } \\
&= \overline{\langle (P^{-1})^* B P^*, A\rangle} \\
&= \langle A, (P^{-1})^* B P^{*}\rangle \\
&= \langle A, T_{P^*}(B)\rangle
\end{align}

Thus, assuming I didn't make any mistakes, we have that $(T_P)^* = T_{P^*}$. (There may be a few steps which are redundant but here's what I came up with so far)

**Remark**: In hindsight, I realize that the solution I presented above is an extremely "follow your nose and see where it leads" method. But once you know that the answer is supposed to be $(T_P)^* = T_{P^*}$, the proof can be shortened much more (even though it's not that long anyway)